# How to upload multi part data from forms to google drive using multer and google drive apis in node.js?

Tags: node.js, multer

Currently the image gets stored in my upload folder. Since i am new to node.js and multer can anyone guide me on how to store these images to google drive?
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs
When through these link but dont know how to implement it in my project. The code provided in this link uploades an image to google drive but the path of the file has to be harcoded. Can anyone please help me out. I am beginner in back end development.
here is my code for reference

````
     ```
     const express = require("express");
     const router = express.Router();
     const multer = require("multer");
     const path = require("path");
     //set storage engine
     const storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: "./public/uploads/",
     filename: function(req, file, cb) {
     cb(null,file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
     }
     });
     //init upload
     const upload = multer({
     storage: storage,
     limits: { fileSize: 10000000 },
     fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
     checkFileType(file, cb);
     }
     }).single("myImage");

     //check file type
     function checkFileType(file, cb) {
     //Allowed ext
     const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
     //check ext
     const extname = fileTypes.test(
     path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase()
     );
     //check mime
     const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);

     if (mimetype && extname) {
       return cb(null, true);
     } else {
     cb("Error: Images Only!");
     }
     }

     router.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("./index"));

     router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
     upload(req, res, err => {
     if (err) {
      res.render("index", {
      msg: err
      });
     } else {
     //   console.log(req.file);
     //   res.send("test");
     if (req.file == undefined) {
       res.render("index", {
       msg: "Error: No File Selected!"
      });
      } else {
      res.render("index", {
      msg: "File uploaded!",
      file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
       });
      }
     }
     });
     });

     module.exports = router;
     ```
````